# Display a block on front page only

Tags: views, theming, blocks

How do I only show a block on the front page. I have  on only listed pages under block settings and it won't disappear on the second page. I've also added

```
$is_front
drupal_is_front_page
```

around the block and those don't work either. Renaming page to page--front.tpl.php didn't work either. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Also please be specific with your answers as I have no idea what to do and I hope this doesn't need a moldule as I'm trying to run a site with little running modules as possible.

Thanks,
Gregory S.

Comment: are you displaying the block programmatically? if so, show the code you are using, and explain what file holds the code

Comment: How I display the block on page.tpl.php 
`<?php print render($page['featured']); ?>`

Comment: It's a block called featured.

Comment: This is my setup in the block - http://towersignal.com/drupal-front.jpg

Comment: How are you adding 'featured' to the page variable?

Comment: Block assigned to region (featured), region is on page.tpl.php

Comment: you said you are adding a block and used code to emphasize that fact, suggesting you are adding the block via code, which means given the code you provided, you are assigning $page['featured'] somewhere with the block array, and then rendering it in page.tpl.php. If that's not the case, you haven't explained what you are actually doing very well at all, and should not be using $is_front, etc - those would only apply if you are rendering the block via code

Comment: block is called first-post, if that helps.

Comment: How do you apply a block directly to the page?

Comment: unless you have a very specific reason (your case does not appear to be one of those) for manually adding a block to the tpl file, you shouldn't. You deleted a comment that better explained the problem, which you should add to the question. and what do you mean by 'second page'?

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a bug because I'm having the same problem on a drupal garden site I set up with the same thing I'm doing here. <front> doesn't work with me.

Comment: well it's not a bug in core, I do it all the time without issue, as I'm sure 100's of 1000's of other people do. It sounds like something else is interfering with the normal Drupal systems for block display/access on your sites

Comment: I didn't delete anything, stackexchange deleted it. And I'm getting tired of this site becuase all of my questions get deleted because it's not SEO worthy.

Comment: This is what got deleted: Views is called first post, block is called first-post. That block is assigned to a region called featured, that region is on page.tpl.php

Comment: node is the page, the default. If I use node/* then it removes the block on every page, which shows that it works. node/0, node/1, node/2 doesn't work. Neither does node?page=1, node?page=2, etc.

Comment: geoff - can you provide an example of what you did to get it working? I've uninstalled every module, cleared cache, nothing. I'm now at if ($is_front) and that shows the text across every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Danno solution is good to go
On visibility settings > Show block on specific pages. Selected: Only the listed pages:

this is the best way.
Are you sure you have checked the only listed pages or you can slect the php checkbox and write some php code.

Comment: How do I enable PHP in the box? And what do I type?

Comment: This is what my block configure page looks like - http://towersignal.com/drupal-block.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is correct. 
On visibility settings > Show block on specific pages.
Selected: Only the listed pages:

```
<front>
```

Your problem might be that the second page is caching. And it is still showing on that page. Or you have another module conflicting and displaying the blocks.
Is your site publicly visible. Can you provide a URL?

Comment: no matter what I do, it's either on every page or none. Even `($page > 1)` doesn't work and I uninstalled every module I'm using.

It's an internal site but I'll setup a temporary one tomorrow. I have a Drupal Garden site and even that one doesn't work.

Comment: The $page > 1 wouldn't ever work for anything in Drupal unless you are putting an if statement. Here is the doc page: https://www.drupal.org/node/21870 if you have tried <front> in the admin UI and it is showing on other pages you should clear the site cache, if that still doesn't work you need to check if those pages are all promoted to front page, edit the page and check those settings. Blocks are not hard to deal with once you get the hang of them and are pretty well tested, reading the docs closely will give you the best insight.

Comment: What I did: nuked my setup, downloaded 7.38, installed 7.38 with minimum settings, used the garland theme, added 6 posts with 3 posts per page in articles content type, moved power by drupal blocked to the footer region, added <front> to only the listed pages.

Still on every page!

Cleared cache, still there.

Comment: So I figured out that front is for the entire pages on front page (1,2,3,etc.) I noticed this because blocks disappear on node pages. So what I'm going to do is load more posts on ajax. Thanks for all the help and sorry for posting alot of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the drupal block programmatically by using block_load() function. If you want to render any block in tpl file you can use the below snippet.

```
$block = block_load('MODULENAME', 'delta');
$output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)))); 
print $output;
```

Comment: delta is the name of the block? modulename required?

Comment: to know about delta and module name, visit http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94100/how-can-i-get-the-delta-of-block-created-using-ui